# how to unstack a series

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

I grouped a data like below which returns a series and column 2 is multi layers

```
grouped = data.groupby(['Column_1','Column_2','Column_3']).size()
```

Now I want to unstack only Column_2 which is a categorical data and have each category as a column. I am able to easily achieve this with only two columns.

Please any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: `grouped.unstack(1)` should get you there.

Comment: @Manakin You are a life saver. Why don't you make this an answer. It may as well help a newbie in future as me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by Manakin, `grouped.unstack(1)` worked for me.